# Meteor: Setting handlebars variable true/false

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm pretty new to this whole handlebars concept but basically I want to be able to set a variable to true on the click of a button and then back to false again from submitting a form in the template that is displayed only if the variable is true.

For the body I have the following code:

```
<body>
{{#if notification}} 
    {{> notifier}}
{{else}}
    {{#if currentUser}}
        {{> dashboard}}
    {{else}}
        {{> login}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
</body>
```

Lets say I have a link in the dashboard which runs in the client js with the id `noticationTestLink`, what would I put in the dashboard events for the following function:

```
'click #noticationTestLink' : function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

if I wanted to set the `notification` variable to true (this is the notification that I refer to in the body).

I'm pretty sure I could figure out the rest if I know how to do this.  Please excuse my lack of experience/knowledge in using handlebars.  I'm also pretty new to just using Meteor.  Thanks in advance!

PS:  I may be completely on the wrong track with this, but that's why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to believe no one has answered this question yet!

**js:**

```
'click #noticationTestLink' : function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   Session.set('notification',true);
}

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  notification: function(){
    return Session.get('notification');
  }
});
```

You need a template, Meteor will wrap it with `<body>...</body>` automatically:

```
 <template name="myTemplate">
   {{#if notification}} 
     {{> notifier}}
   {{else}}
     {{#if currentUser}}
       {{> dashboard}}
     {{else}}
       {{> login}}
     {{/if}}
   {{/if}}
 </template>
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up figuring it out myself after some more searching.  My method involved using Template.body.helpers ({...}); which also worked rather than putting it into a main template, will this bite me later?

Comment: As soon as you start having more templates, yes. You'll need a router too (flow-router or iron-router).